# Squid request_header_add with https

Tags: proxy, https, squid

I'm trying to configure my squid proxy to add a header to all my requests. There is nothing fancy about the configuration. I have the following:

```
request_header_add X-Custom-Header "customheadervalue" all
```

This works for http requests but it will not add any headers for https requests. Is there any configuration I should be doing to make this work? Shouldn't squid be able to add this header to the request before the https is made?

Additionally I noticed that x-forwarded-for is also omitted over https but not on http. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the following in my squid.conf:

```
http_port 3128 accel defaultsite=my.httpsServer.com protocol=HTTPS vport=8443 allow-direct no-vhost
request_header_add X-Custom-Header "customheadervalue" all
```

It seems to be working fine. All my requests to the proxy (made over http) are rewritten in https with the custom header parameter. This seems to be exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

In most scenario's with SSL Squid isn't forwarding the request on your behalf, which is what allows Squid to modify the traffic and insert additional headers on plain HTTP request. With HTTPS/SSL/TLS Squid allows your browser to [CONNECT](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS) directly to the HTTPS host.

Squid only forwards the encrypted traffic between your browser and the remote server, which, because it is encrypted, duh, can't be modified by Squid. No headers can be inserted because the HTTP headers are within the encrypted data stream.

The subtlety is the difference between *forwarding a request*, which implies the understanding of the HTTP protocol and *forwarding encrypted packets* where the HTTP protocol is encrypted and hidden in the TCP/IP stream.

Comment: That makes sense. So instead could I do the following then? :

Client request (HTTP) -> Squid proxy (Adds header, forwards request to HTTPS) -> Server (HTTPS)

Comment: @user313551, if you really think you need this you have to setup squid to perform a MITM for the https session.  It is a not trivial to setup because you must build your own CA, and inject the root cert into all browsers behind the proxy.  See: http://serverfault.com/search?q=squid+https+bump